# How to get private repositories of a organization from github to angular

Tags: angular, api, github, repository

I'm trying to get the all private repositories of a organization which I have access, to list down in angular.

I have created a Personal access token for the user and created a oAuth application in the github organization which I created.

I use this endpoint: [https://api.github.com/orgs/thesis-solutions/repos?{?type=private,page,per_page,sort}](https://api.github.com/orgs/thesis-solutions/repos?%7B?type=private,page,per_page,sort%7D)

and pass the access token in the header.

Comment: What exactly is your response from the API call? And what does your current code look like? We need more info to be able to help.

Comment: This returns a empty due to no public repositories in the organization, 1 private repository only.